# Searching a list to get index values in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string comma separated list of some data. I have another list of strings of keywords that i want to search for in the first list. I want to have returned to me the index of all the elements in the first list that do no contain any of the keywords in the second list. For example:

```
List 1:
Student,101256,Active
Professor,597856,Active
Professor,697843,Inactive
Student,329741,Active
Student,135679,Inactive
Student,241786,Inactive

List 2:
697843
241786
```

My query on List 1 should be, give me all the index of all the elements that do not contain any of the elements of list 2. Therefore, the return list of indices should be 0,1,3,4. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is my try:

```
List<int> index = list1
        .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
        .Where(e => !list2.Contains(e.s))
        .Select(e => e.i).ToList();
```

Comment: There are several ways you can do this, what have you already tried?
Step one should be getting the information into a more manageable format, having to do string splits on commas to do anything is going to be a nightmare!

Comment: Ive tried the above which i got from another post on this forum but it does not work for me:

Comment: @Holly This site is not a forum, it is a Q&A, check this link for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: what alternative would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reference System.Linq, this has now been edited to include the !Student filter

```
var list1 = new List<string> {
  {"Student,101256,Active"},
  {"Professor,597856,Active"}, 
  {"Professor,697843,Inactive"}, 
  {"Student,329741,Active"},
  {"Student,135679,Inactive"},
  {"Student,241786,Inactive"}
};
var list2 = new List<string> {{"697843"}, {"241786"}};

var result = list1
             .Select((item,i)=> new {index=i,value=item})
             .Where(item => !item.value.StartsWith("Student"))
             .Where(item => !item.value.Split(',').Any(j => list2.Contains(j)))
             .Select(item=>item.index)
             .ToList();
```

The first select extracts the index before filtering, the pre-edited version calculated the index after the filter and so was incorrect.

Comment: Vale, your method above works perfectly! i was just wondering, is there a way to tweak the query a little to include the criteria list1 should not start with student?

Comment: `list1.Where(oneItem=> !oneItem.StartsWith("Student")).Where(...` and just continue as he posted. Chain as many filtering methods as you want.

Comment: hmm i tried just what you suggested ANeeves but for some reason, as soon as i try the second where statement, it doesnt work anymore

Comment: this is not working for me actually. i was getting a false reading before. Can you please recommend any fixes?

Comment: @Bob Vale can you suggest an alternative please?